# Is there a SSIS-like feature in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql, ssis

We are using the [SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) in SQL 2008 R2 to copy database tables from 30+ databases (running on SQL Server 2000) to a single database for data analysis purposes on a daily basis. Is there a SSIS-like feature in PostgreSQL? As we are thinking to migrate our database to open source database in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Bucardo might be of interest if you can accept real-time replication instead of batching.

Comment: Thanks Craig! Will check this out. Hopefully it's not too difficult to learn.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, you have a working database solution and you clearly already have the licenses, why would you want to migrate and have all the problems attendant in a migration of data and code? Migrating to a different database is generally a months long, very risky project.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SQL Server Integration Services for that. Just connect to your PostgreSQL using a ODBC connection!
I do it myself.

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL itself doesn't have ETL module similar to ssis, however there are some open-source BI stacks. The most popular open-source ETL toolkit is probably [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/)'s tool [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/). It's recommended on [Postgres wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Migrating_from_one_database_to_another_with_Pentaho_ETL)

Answer (score 1):

There is `pg_dump` which generates an SQL script that can be replayed on another database. Some scripting will be required to gather data from your 30 databases.

To avoid confusion, note that in Postgres, a "database" can contain multiple "schemas" -- in SQL Server, an "instance" can contain multiple "databases". The core concepts are roughly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks user946850! Agree that we can write scripts to copy data from source database to target database. However, am wondering whether this is the most efficient method?